# How to generate free functions

Tags: c++, c, templates, callback, wrapper

### Problem

I've got a C-like API, that I don't have control over, with functions to register/unregister event callbacks:

```
enum Event { Evt1, Evt2, Evt3 }; // events generated by API library
typedef void(__cdecl *Callback)(Event e, void* context);
void API_add_callback(Event e, Callback cb, void* context);
void API_remove_callback(Event e, Callback cb, void* context);
```

I went to create a wrapper base class `APIClient` to encapsulate this API like so:

```
class APIClient
{
  public:
    APIClient(){}

  protected:

    // this is to be used by subclasses
    void subscribe(const set<Event>& events)
    {
      _events = events;
      set<Event>::const_iterator it;
      for (it = _events.begin(); it != _events.end(); ++it)
      {
        API_add_callback(e, &callback, this);
      }
    }

    // this is to be used by subclasses
    void unsubscribe()
    {
      set<Event>::const_iterator it;
      for (it = _events.begin(); it != _events.end(); ++it)
      {
        API_remove_callback(e, &callback, this);
      }
    }

    // this is to be implemented by subclasses
    virtual void on_event(Event e) = 0;

  private:

    // this is the proxy callback that we register for all events
    static void __cdecl callback(Event e, void* context)
    {
      APIClient* instance = (APIClient*)context;

      // forward the event to the subclass
      instance->on_event(e);
    }

    set<Event> _events;
};
```

So far so good, I thought. Then I made two subclasses, `Foo` and `Bar` that are `APIClient`s:

```
// This one is interested in Evt1 and Evt2 of the API...
class Foo : public APIClient
{
  public:

    Foo() : APIClient()
    {
      set<Event>s;
      s.insert(Evt1);
      s.insert(Evt2);
      subscribe(s);
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
      unsubscribe();
    }

  protected:

    virtual void on_event(Event e)
    {
      // here e will be Evt1 or Evt2, whenever they are fired
      // by the API
    }
};

// And this one is interested in Evt2 and Evt3 of the API...
class Bar : public APIClient
{
  public:

    Bar() : APIClient()
    {
      set<Event>s;
      s.insert(Evt2);
      s.insert(Evt3);
      subscribe(s);
    }

    ~Bar()
    {
      unsubscribe();
    }

  protected:

    virtual void on_event(Event e)
    {
      // here e will be Evt2 or Evt3, whenever they are fired
      // by the API
    }
};
```

Trouble is, it doesn't work ... **because the library behind the API determines a unique subscription based on event and callback, not the context** (the context is just additional, optional, user data). So, in general, as it turned out, after

```
API_add_callback(Evt2, &callback, instance_of_Foo);
API_add_callback(Evt2, &callback, instance_of_Bar);
```

only the second subscription wins, so `Foo` never hears of `Evt2`.

### My failed solution attempt

Since is appears that the API requires a specific callback (i.e. a different address) for every new subscription for the same event I thought: code generation ... templates!
After templatizing APIClient, something like `&APIClient<Foo>::callback` and `&APIClient<Bar>::callback` should give me different addresses, right? Wrong! It only generates different addresses (that is, different functions) if they're sufficiently different.

So

```
template<typename T>
class APIClient
{
    // ... other code ...

    static void __cdecl callback(Event e, void* context)
    {
      APIClient* instance = (APIClient*)context;

      // forward the event to the subclass
      instance->on_event(e);
    }
}
```

is no good. But the following would force a template instantiation for `T=Foo` and `T=Bar`, thus giving me `&APIClient<Foo>::callback != &APIClient<Bar>::callback`:

```
template<typename T>
class APIClient
{
    // ... other code ...

    static void __cdecl callback(Event e, void* context)
    {
      APIClient* instance = (APIClient*)context;

      // Use T here explicitely to force different template
      // instantiations of APIClient<T>::callback
      T::call_something();

      // forward the event to the subclass
      instance->on_event(e);
    }
}
```

This is no good. It looks like I'm trying to outsmart the compiler to make it generate what seems to be redundant code, and I think I am doomed to fail :)

### Question (finally)

- Is there a clean way (without singletons and all) to solve my original problem?
- Is there a way to do it the template way, making sure that I get different functions for each instantiation of `APIClient<T>::callback` without doing anything ugly?

*Note: C++11 is ruled out, unfortunately.*

Comment: You'll need class static member functions that take a pointer to an instance of their class as the `void*` param for your classes `Foo` and `Bar` to provide as the callbacks.

Comment: What about using a lambda as the callback? Works here (not in VS2010) for ReadFileEx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075778/c11-lambda-as-callback-of-readfileex/22076528#22076528

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: yeah, well, I forgot to add the no-c++11 restriction ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This something called the curiously recurring template pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
template<typename T>
class APIClient
{
  public:
    APIClient(){}

  protected:

    // this is to be used by subclasses
    void subscribe(const set<Event>& events)
    {
      _events = events;
      set<Event>::const_iterator it;
      for (it = _events.begin(); it != _events.end(); ++it)
      {
         API_add_callback(it, &(T::callback), this);
      }
    }

    // this is to be used by subclasses
    void unsubscribe()
    {
      set<Event>::const_iterator it;
      for (it = _events.begin(); it != _events.end(); ++it)
      {
        API_remove_callback(it, &(T::callback), this);
      }
    }

  private:

    // this is the proxy callback that we register for all events
    static void __cdecl callback(Event e, void* context)
    {
       T * instance = (T*)context;

      // forward the event to the subclass
      instance->on_event(e);
    }

    set<Event> _events;
};
```

The important change is that callback now uses `T * instance`.  This makes access an issue.  You have a few options on how to get around that.  You can leave `on_event` as virtual or remove it from `APIClient` completely as I have done.  The sub-classes still need to implement it, but it can either be public or `APIClient` can be a friend of the sub-classes.

Comment: +1 from me + demo of what this guy is saying: http://ideone.com/x4uMPC  My bad idea was to use a struct and callback pointer: http://ideone.com/Ec2sBg

Comment: Actually, as I see now, the reason why your code worked is not because of `T* instance` instead of `APIClient* instance`, it is precisely because you removed `on_event` completely. So now, instead of a single template-instantiated `callback` calling into the vtable, two template-instantiated `callback`s are created calling completely unrelated functions `Foo::on_event` and `Bar::on_event`. It's a pity I cannot leave the virtual, but whatever :) I'll accept the answer if you update it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I put `on_event` back into `APIClient` and Visual Studio generated unique functions in a debug build.  However in a release build it consolidated them.